# React native image save on asset folder of the react native project

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I have a image URL and I need to it store on locally my project folder. it means in the `src/components/assets/image` path. so how it doing in react native android CLI. Please help me to do that.

I tried with [rn-fetch-blob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-fetch-blob) library. I think my approach was wrong.

```
const saveImageToAssetFolder = async (imagePath) => {
    const assetFolderPath = `${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir}`; 
    const imageName = 'profileImages.jpg'; // Set the desired file name
    
    const targetPath = `${assetFolderPath}/${imageName}`;
  
    try {
      await RNFetchBlob.fs.cp(imagePath, targetPath);
      console.log('Image saved successfully.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error saving image:', error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: `think my approach was wrong.` Indeed. That code makes no sense. And you are not using an url. Or something with that .,/assets/. path.

Comment: so i cant understand to set the path. please help me @blackapps

Comment: I wonder what this has to do with Android as all what has to be done on your PC is downloading an image file and place it in a directory of your project. You can do that with any browser on your pc.

Comment: this is for profile image of the user. it should be inside the project. this is from client requirement. he want to do this that kind way

Comment: You did not react to my remark and question.

Comment: i need to do that while user changing own profile picture when logged in to app